# Change Altium Net Wire / Track Connector in Schematic Editor

Tags: altium

In the Altium schematic editor, is it possible to flip a net object so the text stays read-able but a wire connects on the right hand side of the net?

No matter how I flip or rotate, the net connector is always to the left of the text.

I've bounced into this so many times, I'm hoping there is some Altium way to change this behavior.

I want the connection point under the C in "INDIC" not under the C in "CHG"

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: Oh man, I am seeing some back in 2013: "Re - Net-labels: Altium doesn't support much flexibility in the way of net-labels, and justifiably so, I think. Net labels are grossly overused as it is." -- maybe not...?  I don't work in Altium lots.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. As far as I know, the connecting point on the label is always at the lower left corner.

Comment: Appreciate it Mr. Photon, good to see you bouncing around.  I've got RF 100 ohm differential to 50 ohm post coming up next! I've only ever done a single ended TX layout.

Comment: Generally net labels should have a wire running all the way beneath them to indicate that they are tied to that wire, because of this it doesn't matter if the connector to the net label is on the left or right, because there shouldn't be 'air' underneath it.

Comment: @laptop2d -- ah ha, there is a standard?  Like I said, I'm not a full time layout guy...!  I'm trying to get my schematics a bit more presentable.  I can live with that as a rule.

Comment: @Leroy105 more of an unwritten standard. A schematic should be readable and there shouldn't be any question about what the schematic is communicating. You can't see the x or the dot where the net label connects to a wire on the screen readily. When printing the netllabels out on paper there is no indication (I guess that's nice that you know it's always in the same spot). So I'd rather eliminate all confusion and put the wire right under the netlabel so there is no question of which wire owns it